# How do I listen to STDIN input without pausing my script?

Tags: ruby

I have a `while` loop consistently listening to incoming connections and outputting them to console. I would like to be able to issue commands via the console without affecting the output. I've tried:

```
Thread.new do
    while true
        input   = gets.chomp
        puts "So I herd u sed, \"#{input}\"."
        #Commands would be in this scope
    end
end
```

However, that seems to pause my entire script until input is received; and even then, some threads I have initiated before this one don't seem to execute. I've tried looking at TCPSocket's `select()` method to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure where are the commands you want to "continue running" in your example. Try this small script:

```
Thread.new do
  loop do
    s = gets.chomp
    puts "You entered #{s}"
    exit if s == 'end'
  end
end

i = 0
loop do
  puts "And the script is still running (#{i})..."
  i += 1
  sleep 1
end
```

Reading from STDIN is done in a separate thread, while the main script continues to work.

Comment: The `i` loop only executes only after I enter an input. :/

Comment: In that case, Ruby on Windows sucks. :/

Comment: Sorry; it seems I was using 1.8.6 instead of 1.9.2. I updated and it's working perfectly now. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ruby uses green threads, so blocking system calls will block all threads anyway. An idea:

```
require 'io/wait'

while true
  if $stdin.ready?
    line = $stdin.readline.strip
    p "line from stdin: #{line}"
  end
  p "really, I am working here"
  sleep 0.1
end
```

Comment: `script.rb:33:in `ready?': An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. (Errno::ENOTSOCK)`. Also, my sockets are in a separate script and are executed there, not the main script where I'm trying to add to commands to.

Comment: @salt, are you using windows?

Comment: @salt. bummer, windows does not support "select" on non-socket descriptors, so I have no idea what you can do.