# how do I pause then resume a Ruby script if any key is pressed?

Tags: ruby

I want to pause a Ruby script if any key is pressed, then later resume if any key is pressed. How do I do that? For example, here is a code snippet that doesn't work:

```
pause = false

Thread.new do
  loop do
    if $stdin.ready? and $stdin.getc
      puts "got #{s}"
      pause ^= true # toggle pause variable
    end
  end # loop do
end # Thread.new

loop do
  next if pause == true
  # do stuff if not paused
end # loop do
```

Comment: Have a look at this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681899/how-do-i-listen-to-stdin-input-without-pausing-my-script - it may help

Comment: try removing the `$stdin.ready?` - it is not always supported...

Comment: Thanks guys I'll check out ur solutions.

Comment: Almost working. The solution seems to be using Thread local variables in the correct manner http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Thread.html#method-i-thread_variables

Answer (score 0):

First do `require 'io/console'` Only works in Ruby >= 2.0

```
pause = false

while STDIN.getch != "\r"
 if pause == true
    puts "do something"
end
  pause = !pause
end
```

This will resume the code for every key press alternatively.