# Ruby get input only if input exists

Tags: ruby, input

I am looking for a way to take input from a terminal in a function called from the main loop of a program.

I am not worried about it executing scripts halfway through writing them as the main loop is paused when the application window (not the terminal or console window) loses focus.

This is dev-only so any mishaps with eval lie with me

Edit: I forgot to say, I want the main loop to continue uninterrupted if there is no input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but only because self.reload! is not called while my console window is selected

```
Thread.new do
  loop do
    script_temp = gets
    @script = @script + script_temp
  end
end

def self.reload!
  begin
    eval @script
    $stdout.flush()
  rescue Exception
  end
  @script = ''
end
```

[Based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681899/how-do-i-listen-to-stdin-input-without-pausing-my-script)

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, `Kernel#gets` will return `nil` when there is no more line to read (i.e. EOF is reached).

So the following script would do the equivalent to the above Java code:

```
script = ''
while line = gets
  script += line
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's just blatantly wrong, and a quick look at the documentation for `gets` (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) will prove it to you: "Returns `nil` at end of file". In fact, there is even an example there doing just that: `print while gets`.

Comment: Kernel#gets will return a newline on a blank line, which will always be true, as @CarySwoveland says. However, the terminal condition here is EOF, not a blank line; Kernel#gets will return a `nil` on EOF, which will always be false. That's the desired behavior.

Comment: Sorry, Chris. I just looked at your code, missing the first line, thinking it was `Kernel#gets`, receiving input from a terminal. I've deleted my comment and will delete this one later. You do need an explicit (file handle) receiver for `gets`, no?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It is Kernel#gets, and you don't need an explicit receiver.

Comment: @mwp, I'm confused. For `gets` in the code above to return `nil`, doesn't `$stdin`  (or is it `$<`?) have to first be reassigned (to a file instance, say)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Nope. Try this: fire up an irb, paste in @ChrisW's code, enter a few lines of data, then press Ctrl-D. Check the value of `script`. It works great.

Comment: stdin is just a file handle. It can be (re)opened, closed, and redirected just like any other file handle. If you start your program from a terminal, it will be connected to the terminal, and if you read from stdin (or use a function that reads from stdin, like Kernel#gets), it will get input from the terminal. You can then press Ctrl-D (or Ctrl-Z on Windows) to send an EOF "character" to close the stdin file handle. I use it all the time. It makes it quick and easy to log out or write a few lines to a file.

Comment: @mwp, Ctrl-D! I didn't know that! It certainly makes sense, though. Thanks.

Comment: Output does not print (eval is not executed) and program only briefly responds to OS when new lines are typed in console

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the input lines as an array and join the elements by newline:

```
script = STDIN.readlines.join("\n")
```

To evaluate it:

```
eval script rescue nil
```

Or:

```
begin
  eval script
rescue
end
```

As you noted in the comments, you can `STDOUT.flush` if you need to. If the Ruby program is ending immediately, there's no need to flush stdout.

Comment: Doesn't work. Output is not printed and program does not respond if no input is provided

Comment: Well, you have to do something with the `script` variable. I don't see a `System.out.println(script)` in your original code, is that what you want to have happen?

Comment: Also, if you open STDIN from any programming language and don't provide any input, it's going to hang. I can't get your Java snippet to compile but I suspect it does the same thing. If you want some other behavior, please edit your question to specify your requirements.

Comment: behold my script evaluation code:
```
    begin \n
      eval script \n
      $stdout.flush() \n
    rescue Exception \n
      return false \n
    end \n
```

edit: formatting no like

Comment: Okay, updated. `rescue Exception` with `return false` is bad form; just put `rescue` with an empty block. And if the Ruby part of your process is ending after this, there's no need to flush stdout.

Comment: this is in a main loop that should be 60 fps, rate is controlled by Graphics.update() at the top of the loop. This function is called towards the bottom of the loop. Graphics.update() pauses the loop if the application window (not my terminal) is not "in focus" (currently selected window)